# Problem in compiling C function with threading on Fedora

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

When I try to compile a C-program with multithreading in Fedora, I get the following error.

The file name is abc.c

```
abc.c:(.text+0x39): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
abc.c:(.text+0x61): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
abc.c:(.text+0x79): undefined reference to `pthread_join'
abc.c:(.text+0x8d): undefined reference to `pthread_join'
```

I checked in /usr/include and I found that pthread.h is present. Also I tried copying pthread.h to the same directory as abc.c

How do I resolve these linking errors?

Comment: gcc -o myexe abc.c -lpthread

???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by George you must link with the thread library
    gcc -o abc abc.c -pthread
The reason you are getting those errors is because during the linking stage the compiler tries to fill in all the slots where it had placed placeholders for method calls that it knew were defined but currently did not know their locations because the appropriate library had not been linked yet. As pointed out by caf using the -pthread flag in both compiling and linking stages allows for the compiler to make smarter choices about what it needs to use to be thread-safe in certain conditions.

Comment: Modern usage is to supply `-pthread` to both compile and link stages (note - no `-l`), which in turn requests that the necessary library is linked.  This also allows the compiler to change its output in other ways to suit the production of multithreaded code.

Comment: I usually compile gcc -c without the -pthread flag but when I do the linking I use -lpthread, is there a difference? I guess if it knows of pthreads during the compile stage it can add optimizations

Comment: I think it depends on the architecture and C library in use as to whether it's a no-op at the compile stage or not.

Comment: Well just compiling without linking as executable leaves the gaps in there for the linker to fill so I'm not sure.

Comment: If the C library uses macros or inline functions, it may need to know if it needs to use a thread-safe version at compile time.

Comment: @caf I see thanks for the tip, I usually work on the kernel so I can't really link any libraries to it but this should help on some other projects I do thanks :)

Comment: @Jesus.. I did.. after somehow figuring out how to accept an answer :)